# Как дополнить список в словаре?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть строка `d[namesp] = {'variables': [arg]}`, она находится в цикле, и мне нужно, чтобы `'variables'` пополнялся новыми аргументами, а не присваивал каждый раз новое значение списку:

```py
NUM = int(input())
d = {}

for i in range(NUM):
    cmd, namesp, arg = input().split()
    if cmd == 'add':
        d[namesp] = {'variables': [arg]}
    elif cmd == 'create':
        d[namesp] = {'parent': arg}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите пример входных и выходных данных в вопрос. Вы можете сделать это, нажав кнопку [edit]

Answer (score 2):

Вы сами практически ответили на свой вопрос. Не нужно каждый раз присваивать новое значение списку. Добавляйте новые элементы с помощью метода [`append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```py
d[namesp]['variables'].append(arg)
```

**UPD:**

Если ключ может не существовать в словаре, то можно воспользоваться методом [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault), который в таком случае установит его со значение по умолчанию:

```py
d.setdefault(namesp, {'variables': []})['variables'].append(arg)
```

Comment: проблема в том, что изначально словаря namesp не существует, как и ключа 'variables', а если их создать заранее то при каждой итерации цикла значение будет обновляться, как в моем примере

Comment: @НикитаПлахотник Если их создать заранее, то всё будет в порядке. Если у Вас не получается, то приведите больше кода ([минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), чтобы была возможность дать Вам более детальный ответ

Comment: `NUM = int(input())
d = {}
for i in range(NUM):
    cmd, namesp, arg = input().split()
    if cmd == 'add':
        d[namesp] = {'variables': [arg]}
    elif cmd == 'create':
        d[namesp] = {'parent': arg}`

Comment: спасибо за помощь!